# Functools extension library

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I wrote a utility library inspired by `functools` that adds some common operations on functions I frequently use in my projects.
As usual I'd appreciate any feed back.

`functoolsplus.py`

```py
"""More higher-order functions and operations on callable objects."""

from dataclasses import dataclass
from time import perf_counter
from functools import wraps
from sys import exit, stderr    # pylint: disable=W0622
from typing import Any, Callable, IO, Optional, Union


__all__ = [
    'coerce',
    'exiting',
    'exitmethod',
    'instance_of',
    'timeit',
    'wants_instance'
]


Decorator = Callable[[Callable[..., Any]], Callable[..., Any]]


@dataclass
class PerfCounter:
    """Performance counter."""

    start: Optional[float] = None
    end: Optional[float] = None
    on_exit: Optional[Callable[..., Any]] = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = perf_counter()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        self.end = perf_counter()

        if self.on_exit is None:
            return None

        if len(self.on_exit.__code__.co_varnames) == 1:
            return self.on_exit(self)

        return self.on_exit()

    @property
    def duration(self) -> float:
        """Return the duration."""
        return self.end - self.start


class exitmethod:   # pylint: disable=C0103
    """Decorator class to create a context manager,
    having the passed function as exit method.
    """

    def __init__(self, function: Callable[..., Any]):
        self.function = function

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        if wants_instance(self.function):
            return self.function(self, typ, value, traceback)

        return self.function(typ, value, traceback)


def coerce(typ: type) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    """Converts the return value into the given type."""

    def decorator(function: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., typ]:
        """Decorates the given function."""
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> typ:
            """Wraps the respective function."""
            return typ(function(*args, **kwargs))

        wrapper.__annotations__['return'] = typ
        return wrapper

    return decorator


def exiting(function: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    """Makes a function exit the program with its return code."""

    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        """Wraps the respective function."""
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        exit(result or 0)

    return wrapper


def instance_of(cls: Union[type, tuple[type]]) -> Callable[[Any], bool]:
    """Returns a callback function to check the instance of an object."""

    return lambda obj: isinstance(obj, cls)


def timeit(file: IO = stderr, flush: bool = False) -> Decorator:
    """Times the execution of the given function."""

    def print_duration(
            function: Callable[..., Any]
    ) -> Callable[[PerfCounter], None]:
        """Prints a perf counter."""

        def inner(ctr: PerfCounter) -> None:
            print('Function', function.__name__, 'took', ctr.duration,
                  file=file, flush=flush)

        return inner

    def decorator(function: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
        """The actual decorator."""
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            """Wraps the original function."""
            with PerfCounter(on_exit=print_duration(function)):
                return function(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


def wants_instance(function: Callable[..., Any]) -> bool:
    """Determines whether the respective function is considered a method."""

    try:
        return function.__code__.co_varnames[0] == 'self'
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

## Usage examples

The following code are example use cases, to get an idea, how the library utilities are meant to be used.

```py
from time import sleep
from typing import Iterator

import functoolsplus    # Change accordingly


with functoolsplus.PerfCounter() as ctr:
    sleep(3)


print('Performace countner:', ctr, ctr.duration)


@functoolsplus.exitmethod
def value_error_guard(typ, value, traceback):

    if isinstance(value, ValueError):
        print('Doing stuff with ValueError:', value)
        return True


with value_error_guard:
    raise ValueError('Darn it.')


@functoolsplus.coerce(frozenset)
def get_squares(n: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    """Yields square numbers from 0 to n-1."""

    for number in range(n):
        yield number ** 2


input('Press enter to view help(get_squares):')
help(get_squares)
print('Squares:', get_squares(5))


NUMBERS = [1, 2, 3.0, 4, 5, 6.2, '42']
INTEGERS = filter(functoolsplus.instance_of(int), NUMBERS)
print('Numbers:', *NUMBERS)
print('Integers:', *INTEGERS)


@functoolsplus.timeit(flush=True)
def timed_sleep(seconds: float) -> None:

    return sleep(seconds)


timed_sleep(3)


class Foo:

    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 42

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        return cls()

    @staticmethod
    def spamm():
        pass


print('Foo.foo() wants instance:', functoolsplus.wants_instance(Foo.foo))
print('Foo.bar() wants instance:', functoolsplus.wants_instance(Foo.bar))
print('Foo.spamm() wants instance:', functoolsplus.wants_instance(Foo.spamm))


@functoolsplus.exiting
def main(exit_code: int) -> int:

    print('Exiting with exit code:', exit_code)
    return exit_code


main(42)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't find `PerfCounter` to be well-modelled as a class. `start` and `end` aren't valid on construction, which should be a red flag. The current contract also allows for the calling user to initialise `start` and `end` themselves, which doesn't make sense; so even if this were to be modelled as a class it shouldn't be a `@dataclass`. The more natural calling pattern is, I think, a plain function that accepts a function reference, calls it, and returns a `float` - which already exists, and is called `timeit` (not your `timeit`; the built-in `timeit`). On that note, probably not a good idea to overlap with that name. P.S.: why support a callback? If you're already decorating code, you have access to the part of the code immediately after execution, so why not... just do something there, instead of registering a callback?

Anything that depends on `want_instance` is a symptom of non-ideal application design. You should already know whether everything is an instance method or not.