# Unit tests coverage of functools extension library

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

A few days ago I requested a review of my [functools extension library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272874/functools-extension-library).
Since I did not have any unit tests for it, I started writing some for the revised version of this library. I'd like some feedback on whether these tests are sensible and how they may be improved upon.

## Revised library (test subject)

`functoolsplus.py`

```py
"""More higher-order functions and operations on callable objects."""

from functools import partial, wraps
from typing import Any, Callable, Union


__all__ = ['coerce', 'exit_function', 'exit_method', 'instance_of']


class exit_function:    # pylint: disable=C0103
    """Decorator class to create a context manager,
    having the passed function as exit function.
    """

    def __init__(self, function: Callable[..., Any], *, method: bool = False):
        self.function = function
        self.method = method

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        if self.method:
            return self.function(self, typ, value, traceback)

        return self.function(typ, value, traceback)


exit_method = partial(exit_function, method=True)


def coerce(typ: type) -> Callable[[Callable[..., Any]], Callable[..., Any]]:
    """Converts the return value into the given type."""

    def decorator(function: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., typ]:
        """Decorates the given function."""
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> typ:
            """Wraps the respective function."""
            return typ(function(*args, **kwargs))

        wrapper.__annotations__['return'] = typ
        return wrapper

    return decorator


def instance_of(cls: Union[type, tuple[type]]) -> Callable[[Any], bool]:
    """Returns a callback function to check the instance of an object."""

    return lambda obj: isinstance(obj, cls)
```

## Unit tests

`test_coerce.py`

```py
"""Test coerce() function."""

from typing import Any, Iterator
from unittest import TestCase

from functoolsplus import coerce


@coerce(set)
def test_coerce_set(*args, **kwargs) -> Iterator[Any]:
    for arg in args:
        yield arg

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        yield key
        yield value


class TestCoerce(TestCase):

    def test_type_hint(self):
        self.assertEqual(test_coerce_set.__annotations__['return'], set)

    def test_return_type(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(test_coerce_set(), set)

    def test_return_value(self):
        self.assertSetEqual(
            test_coerce_set('some', 42, 'args', keyword=True, other=None),
            {'some', 42, 'args', 'keyword', True, 'other', None}
        )
```

`text_exit_function.py`

```py
"""Test exit_function() decorator."""

from unittest import TestCase

from functoolsplus import exit_function


@exit_function
def test_function(typ, value, traceback):
    if typ is None and value is None:
        return True

    if issubclass(typ, Exception) and isinstance(value, Exception):
        return True


class TestExitFunction(TestCase):
    """Test exit_function()."""

    def test_type(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(test_function, exit_function)

    def test_is_context_manager(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(test_function, '__enter__'))
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(test_function, '__exit__'))

    def test_context(self):
        with test_function as manager:
            self.assertIsInstance(manager, exit_function)
            self.assertTrue(hasattr(manager, '__exit__'))

    def test_exception_handling(self):
        with test_function:
            raise Exception()
```

`test_exit_method.py`

```py
"""Test exit_method() decorator."""

from unittest import TestCase

from functoolsplus import exit_function, exit_method


@exit_method
def test_method(self, typ, value, traceback):
    assert isinstance(self, exit_function)

    if typ is None and value is None:
        return True

    if issubclass(typ, Exception) and isinstance(value, Exception):
        return True


class TestExitMethod(TestCase):
    """Test exit_method()."""

    def test_type(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(test_method, exit_function)

    def test_is_context_manager(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(test_method, '__enter__'))
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(test_method, '__exit__'))

    def test_context(self):
        with test_method as manager:
            self.assertIsInstance(manager, test_method)
            self.assertTrue(hasattr(manager, '__exit__'))

    def test_exception_handling(self):
        with test_method:
            raise Exception()
```

`test_instance_of.py`

```py
"""Test instance_of() function."""

from unittest import TestCase

from functoolsplus import instance_of


ITEMS = ('string', 42, 'other string', 3.14, 1337, True, False, None)


class TestInstanceOf(TestCase):

    def test_filter_str(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(filter(instance_of(str), ITEMS)),
            ['string', 'other string']
        )

    def test_filter_int(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(filter(instance_of(int), ITEMS)),
            [42, 1337, 1, 0]
        )

    def test_filter_float(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(filter(instance_of(float), ITEMS)),
            [3.14]
        )

    def test_filter_bool(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(filter(instance_of(bool), ITEMS)),
            [True, False]
        )

    def test_map_str(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(map(instance_of(str), ITEMS)),
            [True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
        )

    def test_map_int(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(map(instance_of(int), ITEMS)),
            [False, True, False, False, True, True, True, False]
        )

    def test_map_float(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(map(instance_of(float), ITEMS)),
            [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False]
        )

    def test_map_bool(self):
        self.assertSequenceEqual(
            list(map(instance_of(bool), ITEMS)),
            [False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False]
        )
```